# Solo GPU mining

Tags: gpu-mining, solo-mining

I've literally searched every source available to find an answer but the only thing I've came up with is that I have to set my own pool in order to do that. I am using Windows 7 and the only available guides for setting a pool is for Linux and OSx. 
Specs: Windows 7, AMD FX 8320 @ 3.5 GHz, 4GB RAM, GTX 750 Ti 2GB

Does anybody know if it's possible and if yes, how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Very good question. Your hashrate will be too low to make any money this way, but it helps the network the most.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to use a pool? Illuminati? :P

Comment: I did use a pool but the shares are garbage, for 24hours mining my share is 0.06. I don't say it's unfair but since I am consuming electric power to mine why not try solo mining with much bigger profit If I ever find a block but deep inside I know it will never happen.

Comment: you can now use xmrpool.net on a solo-mining port, very simple to use any mining software you want

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can solo mine without using a private pool. Hyc modified ccminer and wolf's AMD miner to be able to do solo mining. Unfortunately, no binaries have been made for windows for nvidia version.

https://github.com/hyc/ccminer-cryptonight

Wolf's has windows binaries

https://github.com/wolf9466/wolf-xmr-miner

For ccminer you use a URL of the form
`"daemon+tcp://<host>:<port>/json_rpc"`

For Wolf's you use
`"daemon+tcp://<host>:<port>"`

For Wolf's miner, if your daemon RPC is bound to an IP address of e.g. 192.168.1.177

`minerd -o daemon+tcp://192.168.1.177:18081 -u <address> -p x`

Similarly, if you can get the nvidia one compiled somehow, it's

`ccminer -o daemon+tcp://192.168.1.177:18081/json_rpc -u <address> -p x`

Comment: How to do it with xmr-stak-nvidia?

Comment: hi; you wrote "if your daemon RPC is bound to an IP address of e.g. 192.168.1.177", how can i see that? By using ipconfig, or a command in daemon? Thanks by advance

Answer (score 5):

For mining Monero (XMR) on GPU in solo mode there is an another way. We can setup Monero Stratum pool (MoneroProxy) from here - https://github.com/sammy007/monero-stratum , and use any miners (such as xmr-stack-cpu, xmr-stack-amd, xmr-stack-nvidia) on every PC at home. As a result - all devices results will be automatically sendes to monerod via RPC.

Comment: monero stratum is not available for windows.

Answer (score 4):

Solo mining is fairly trivial. Note that you have to be fully synced in order to do so. If you are starting from scratch, download the official binaries from [here](https://getmonero.org/downloads/). Subsequently, extract them to a given folder and start `monerod`. This is the daemon which will now start syncing. To check your blockheight type `status` into `monerod`. The blockheight should be equal to the blockheight reported on [MoneroBlocks](http://moneroblocks.info) in order to be fully synced.

Now that you are fully synced, you can start solo mining. To do so you have to type `start_mining <address> [<number-of-threads>]` into the daemon. Thus, if you want to solo mine to, for instance, the [donation address](https://getmonero.org/getting-started/donate/) of the [core-team](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/people) with 2 threads the command would be as follows:

`start_mining 44AFFq5kSiGBoZ4NMDwYtN18obc8AemS33DBLWs3H7otXft3XjrpDtQGv7SqSsaBYBb98uNbr2VBBEt7f2wfn3RVGQBEP3A 2`

Note that the optimal number of threads is one per 2 MB of CPU cache. Thus, if you have 4 MB of CPU cache available the optimal number of threads would be 2.

---

There is also an alternative method, which is to enter the `start_mining` command into `monero-wallet-cli`. You won't have to specify an address then, because it will use the address of the wallet that is opened at that moment. However, you will be able to specify the number of thredas.

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to solo mine with a GPU.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that CPU hashrate will be much lower than my GPU and that's why I am asking to find a way to solo mine but with GPU. I am mining through ccminer at 250H/s at the moment. My monero node is currently at 60% to synchronize.

Comment: My apologies. I kind of misread your question. It's currently not possible to solo mine with your GPU. In order to do so you'd have to set up a private pool.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your answer anyway. I think it's pretty hard to set up my on private pool and the lack of information makes it harder.

Comment: Is the cache only L3? I'm have AMD Opteron 3365, and it has 8 MB on L2 and 8 MB on L3. Should I use 4 or 8 cores?

Comment: Yes. Thus, 4 cores in your situation.