# How to connect to a node with cpuminer

Tags: monerod

For training purposes, I am trying to connect to a private node using the cpuminer-multi but it fails.

Is this command line correct?
cpuminer -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:18080 -u wallet -p x -t 3 --userpass A:B

Daemon runs as: ./monerod --rpi-login A:B

The node ran and synchronized and I made sure that port 18080 is open
on the client, i am trying to connect to the node but I get :
                      Signature mismatch and 
[2017-12-27 15:33:53] stratum_recv_line failed
[2017-12-27 15:33:53] ...retry after 10 seconds

On the node, I get Signature mismatch, connection will be closed

Is there something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command is not correct.

You are connecting a cpuminer, which talks pool language by default, to a daemon's P2P port, which speaks monero P2P.

You need to change two things:

- connect to the RPC port (18081 by default)
- tell the cpuminer to not talk pool language but dameon RPC language using `daemon+tcp` instead of `stratum+tcp`

Not all miners know how to talk to the daemon instead of to a pool, so yours may not be able to. If not, use another miner (or use a more recent version).

For more information, see [Solo GPU mining](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2083/solo-gpu-mining/2086#2086) (partly applies to solo CPU mining).

Comment: I have one more question, do i need to have the monero-wallet-cpi to be running in the background? if my miner findes shares, it sends it out to the daemon but where do i see how many shares i made to the daemon?

Comment: You don't need a wallet running (except when your pool tries to pay miners).

Comment: i have a node and not a pool .. does the node need this wallet-client if it wants to make transactions even if it is not to me?

Comment: The node doesn't make any transactions.